# Error when trying to login to site

Tags: wordpress, authentication, buddypress

I am having an issue I moved my site to online today. At localhost Login page was working perfectly but when I moved the site to online server login page returns a blank page after authentication instead of redirecting me to the user profile, here is the [link](http://www.gms-giki.com/login-page) if you want to test the login page.

My console output is below

```
[13:47:12.109] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://www.gms-giki.com/wp-login.php
[13:47:12.236] Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. @ resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///C:/Users/Anfal/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g6wqsxw1.default/extensions/%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> jar:file:///C:/Users/Anfal/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/g6wqsxw1.default/extensions/%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D.xpi!/lib/requestNotifier.js:64
```

and here is the result of debugging.

```
Notice: bbp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 2.3.) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012

Notice: bp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 1.7.) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012

Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012

Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012

Notice: is_site_admin is deprecated since version 1.5! Use is_super_admin() instead. in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2871

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat/quick-chat.php on line 262

Notice: Undefined index: byrole in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-content/plugins/menu-by-user-role/includes/class.plugin_mur.php on line 162

Notice: Undefined index: byrole in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-content/plugins/menu-by-user-role/includes/class.plugin_mur.php on line 162

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-login.php on line 384

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-login.php on line 396

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 678

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 679

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 680

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3012) in /home/gmsgiki/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875
```

Answer (score -1):

Try naming your plugins folder to plugins_old ...this will deactivate them all. Try logging in again after that.